# small value approximation for $\sinh(\frac{x}{2J})$

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

Except for $x$, all terms are constant and $J \ge 1$.

Been working on this for a while without luck so looking for some help.

Show $Z(x) = \frac{\sinh(2J+1)x}{\ 2J\sinh(\frac{x}{2J})}=2J + 1$ for $x\ll 1$

Attempt:

Let $y = \frac{x}{2J}$

so that we get

$Z(x) = \frac{\sinh(2J+1)(y)}{\sinh(y)}$ but where $x\ll 1$, it is true that $y\ll 1$

so $\sinh(y) = y$

so that $Z(x) = \sinh(2J+1)$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: $\sinh y \neq y$ unless $y=0$. The last conclusion is incorrect, you cannot cancel $y$ from the argument of $\sinh((2J+1)y)$.

Comment: By $\sinh(2J+1)(y)$ they mean $\sinh[(2J+1)(y)]$, not $[\sinh(2J+1)](y)$.

Comment: @J.G.

Made clearer the expression.

Comment: $\sinh(2J+1)x$ probably means $\sinh((2J+1)x)$ and not $(\sinh(2j+1))\cdot x$. Otherwise the statement is not true.

Answer (score 2):

As noticed in the comments, the expression should be interpreted as follows

$$\sinh\color{red}{\left[(2J+1)x\right]}$$

and then we have indeed, by standard limit $\frac{\sinh t}{t} \to 1$ when $t\to 0$

$$\frac{\sinh\left[(2J+1)x\right]}{\ 2J\sinh(\frac{x}{2J})}=\frac{\sinh\left[(2J+1)x\right]}{(2J+1)x}(2J+1)\frac{\frac x{2J}}{\sinh(\frac{x}{2J})} \to 1 \cdot (2J+1) \cdot 1 = 2J+1$$

which allows to conclude that for $x\ll1$

$$Z(x) \approx 2J + 1$$

---

For the standard limit we have as $t\to 0$

$$\frac{\sinh t}{t}=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2t}=\frac1{e^{t}}\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2t} \to 1\cdot 1 =1$$

Comment: The second equality is always a surprise.

Comment: @Mathematicing Are you referring to $\sinh t=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}$?

Comment: I was referring to the use of $(2J+1)x$ in both numerator and denominator.

Comment: @Mathematicing Oh yes, the big trick!